# R - How to convert a column times in ####M #S format to just number of minutes

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I have used lubridate to create a column of time format ####M ##S

`df$delay <- minutes(df$finish-Delays$start)`

How can I covert this column to just give the number #### in front of minutes?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the S4 slots...

```
library(lubridate)

# create data
df <- data.frame(finish = 20)
Delays <- data.frame(start = 10)
(df$delay <- minutes(df$finish-Delays$start))
[1] "10M 0S"

# take a look at the 'delay' object
str(df$delay)
Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  ..@ .Data : num 0
  ..@ year  : num 0
  ..@ month : num 0
  ..@ day   : num 0
  ..@ hour  : num 0
  ..@ minute: num 10

# access the 'minute' slot
df$delay@minute
[1] 10
```